# How do use Wai/Warp with a Database Pool

Tags: haskell

I was wondering if somebody could point me towards the correct direction of how am I supposed to use Wai/Warp with a Database Pool.

Warp `run` is of type `Port -> Application -> IO ()`, where `Application` is  `Request -> (Response -> IO ResponseReceived) -> IO ResponseReceived`

Assuming I have a DB connection somehow,  I don't see how I can wrap my `Application` around that every request share the `ConnectionPool`.

I was thinking maybe doing something like this. Will that work?

```
{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings #-}
import Network.Wai
import Network.HTTP.Types
import Network.Wai.Handler.Warp (run)
import Database.MySQL.Base

createPool = do
    connect
        defaultConnectInfo 
            { ciUser = "username"
            , ciPassword = "password"
            , ciDatabase = "dbname" }

app :: IO MySQLConn -> Application
app conn _ respond = do
    respond $ responseLBS
        status200
        [("Content-Type", "text/plain")]
        "Hello, Web!"

main :: IO ()
main = do
    putStrLn $ "http://localhost:8080/"
    run 8080 $ app $ createPool
```

Comment: What have you tried? What happened?

Comment: It compiles and seems to be working, but that's not the point. I want to be sure I am doing it the recommended/correct way and not creating problems that I don't understand or see as I am pretty new in Haskell